# Is there any way to resize ubuntu root partition without restarting

Tags: partitioning, 21.04

I want to resize the main ubuntu partition but i dont want to use a boot-drive and i don't have another OS on my pc

Answer (score 5):

You are essentially saying "I want to change my bicycle tire, but I don't want to get off my bicycle."

No, you cannot move or shrink a mounted root partition safely.

Comment: Thanks. I’m sure your best option then is to download Ubuntu to a usb and resize from a live usb session. I know you said you don’t want to use a boot drive, but honestly I think that’s your best option!

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can’t resize your Linux partition while it is in use - in fact I don’t think gparted will let you resize a mounted partition at all. The Linux partition must be mounted if you’re using it as the os so it can’t be possible using conventional tools.

I’d answer this by asking you - why would you want to do that? It’s actually very easy to do it from a live usb session, and that is pretty safe. If you’ve recently installed Ubuntu you probably have the required usb to do it.

Any other method will almost certainly be harder and riskier. As per the answer above, you’re doing major work on your vehicle whilst travelling - maybe even more like changing the chassis but keeping the gearbox and engine whilst driving!

Comment: sadly i did install it a long time ago and i want to locate more memory on my root drive